# Multithreading. How to equally share common resources?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

simple code (i know that it is a very bad one, but i made it just for the example):

```
 1 #include <mutex>
 2 #include <iostream>
 3 #include <thread>
 4 
 5 std::mutex mu;
 6 
 7 void myFunc(void) {
 8         for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
 9                 mu.lock();
 10                 std::cout << "CHILD Thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
 11                 mu.unlock();
 12         }
 13 }
 14 
 15 int main()
 16 {
 17         std::thread thr(myFunc);
 18         for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
 19                 mu.lock();
 20                 std::cout << "MAIN Thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
 21                 mu.unlock();
 22         }
 23         thr.join();
 24         return 0;
 25 }
```

returns this kind of output:

```
1      MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
2      MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
3      MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
4      MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
5      MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
6      MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
7      MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
8      CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
9      CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
10     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
11     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
12     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
13     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
14     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
15     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
16     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
17     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
18     MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
19     MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
20     MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
21     MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
22     MAIN Thread: 140581832210240
23     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
24     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
25     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
26     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
27     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
28     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
29     CHILD Thread: 140581814855424
           ....... and so on
```

And as i see it - this output defeats meaning of multithreading because one thread has to wait for other one for long time. This output should simultaneously give me cout of child, cout of main, cout of child, cout of main and so on. I know mutex is not responsible for fair share of common resources but then: who is ? And how do i implement that into my program?

Thank you.

EDIT: putting std::cout into a function:

```
10 void common_cout(string msg) {
11         mu.lock();
12         std::cout << msg << std::endl;
13         mu.unlock();
14 }
```

doesnt help.

Comment: You should not use the same memory space by all threads. This is why you have to use locks and so on. Divide the space equaly so that first thread will  use 1/number_of_threads pice of memory. In that case you don't even need to use locking mechanism.
Check also how many threads may be run on you CPU. It doesn't make sense to run more threads than your CPU supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original code has the same issue in windows, but I switched to using native windows equivalents, and this windows example works the way you'd expect it to, alternating between the two threads. Each instance of ReleaseMutex() results in the "other" thread acquiring the mutex and running. The Sleep(2) in main was an easy way to make sure that myFunc started it's loop first.

I also created a version with main and two threads for a total of three threads. The cycling goes in order, so it appears that Windows native mutex locks are done in the order requested.

For round robin type cycling or general synchronization between threads and/or processes, using one semaphore per thread or process is better since any thread or process can increment (release / signal) any semaphore. The problem with this is a semaphore is not a native part of the standard thread interface, requiring some combination of mutex and condition variable to implement the equivalent of a semaphore. Windows and posix support native semaphores.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

static HANDLE mu;                       // handle: mutex
static HANDLE ht1;                      // handle: thread 1
static DWORD  id1;                      // thread 1 id

DWORD WINAPI myFunc(LPVOID) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        WaitForSingleObject(mu, INFINITE);
        std::cout << "child thread: " << i << std::endl;
        ReleaseMutex(mu);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    mu = CreateMutex(NULL,TRUE,NULL);   // main owns mutex
    ht1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, myFunc, 0, 0, &id1);
    Sleep(2);                           // make sure myFunc running
    ReleaseMutex(mu);                   // release mutex
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        WaitForSingleObject(mu, INFINITE);
        std::cout << "main  thread: " << i << std::endl;
        ReleaseMutex(mu);
    }
    WaitForSingleObject(ht1, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(ht1);
    CloseHandle(mu);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
child thread: 0
main  thread: 0
child thread: 1
main  thread: 1
...
child thread: 18
main  thread: 18
child thread: 19
main  thread: 19
```

3 thread example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

static HANDLE mu;                       // handle: mutex
static HANDLE ht0;                      // handle: thread 0
static HANDLE ht1;                      // handle: thread 1
static DWORD  id0;                      // thread 0 id
static DWORD  id1;                      // thread 1 id

DWORD WINAPI Thread0(LPVOID) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        WaitForSingleObject(mu, INFINITE);
        std::cout << "Thread0 : " << i << std::endl;
        ReleaseMutex(mu);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread1(LPVOID) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        WaitForSingleObject(mu, INFINITE);
        std::cout << "Thread1 : " << i << std::endl;
        ReleaseMutex(mu);
    }
    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI Thread2(LPVOID) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        WaitForSingleObject(mu, INFINITE);
        std::cout << "Thread2 : " << i << std::endl;
        ReleaseMutex(mu);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    mu = CreateMutex(NULL,TRUE,NULL);   // main owns mutex
    ht0 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread0, 0, 0, &id0);
    ht1 = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Thread1, 0, 0, &id1);
    Sleep(2);                           // let other threads get started
    ReleaseMutex(mu);                   // release mutex
    Thread2(0);
    WaitForSingleObject(ht0, INFINITE);
    WaitForSingleObject(ht1, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(ht0);
    CloseHandle(ht1);
    CloseHandle(mu);
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
Thread0 : 0
Thread1 : 0
Thread2 : 0
Thread0 : 1
Thread1 : 1
Thread2 : 1
...
Thread0 : 9
Thread1 : 9
Thread2 : 9
```

Comment: For strictly deterministic round-robin behavior, there's little point in spawning threads at all; just run the code in a loop in a single thread, calling first one work-function, then the other.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - although not demonstrated in this example, the assumption is that there would be significant code unrelated to the shared resource, where multi-threading and/or multi-processing would help. In the case of Windows and embedded systems I've worked on, multi-thread communication and synchronization is done via an inter-thread messaging system that uses linked lists for message queues, along with a mutex and semaphore for each message queue.

Answer (score 1):

> I know mutex is not responsible for fair share of common resources but then: who is ?

the actual scheduling is done by your Operating System.

You haven't said what this is, but it's common *not* to switch between threads more often than necessary, because it's inefficient (there is some cost to the switch).

In other words, your idea of "fairness" - presumably strict round-robin where each thread takes turns - would be an expensive default behaviour. You can anyway code it explicitly if it's what you want. The usual goal of a fair scheduler involves some kind of trade-off between how long a runnable thread has to wait, and how frequently it's reasonable to pre-empt a thread while it's still doing (presumably) useful work.

The OS behaviour also, of course, depends on how many cores you have. You haven't mentioned this either.

> ... And how do i implement that into my program?

If you do some reasonable amount of actual work in your threads, you may find your scheduler behaves more to your liking. This sort of artificial test rarely gives useful results, specifically because you're executing a tiny amount of code in a tight loop.

Comment: If the threads are running on separate cores, then they should both be running at the same time, all the time, without any switching. The issue could be related to how std::cout is handled by the compiler / OS, or how the compiler / OS handles lock and unlock.

Comment: The threads are doing almost _nothing_ except thrashing the same couple of locks, so it's very unlikely they'll really be "running at the same time" very often. The only thing they can do in parallel is the for-loop increment and test, while all the formatting work is protected by mutex (and is itself probably still cheaper than unlocking the mutex)

Comment: The sleeping thread will typically be marked runnable when the running thread unlocks. Then there's a window of approximately {the mutex unlock syscall exit path, plus about 3 loop instructions} for the sleeper to actually get scheduled before the already-running thread successfully locks the mutex again. You can see it isn't going to actually make progress very often until the running thread actually does some I/O (flushing stdout).

Comment: A thread sleeping because it tried to lock a mutex, will be marked runnable when the mutex is unlocked. The already-running thread doesn't yield just because it unlocked the mutex though, and it will almost immediately try re-lock the mutex, and thus almost always succeed. The window of opportunity for the sleeping thread to actually begin execution, between the running thread un-locking and re-locking the mutex, is very small. I have no idea which part of this you disagree with.

Comment: My point was that It wouldn't make sense to mark a thread pending on a lock as runnable without also locking the mutex, but apparently neither happens as you mention, so the current thread keeps on running, while the other thread remains locked on the mutex, even if running on separate cores. I've worked on embedded OS's that would immediately lock the mutex and continue the other thread as soon as an unlock was done, if the other  thread was pending on that mutex. Assuming the thread is running on another core / processor, there's no yeilding involved, both threads run at the same time.

Comment: It's possible that a lock could perform a context save before checking the lock, which would allow the thread to be marked runnable without locking the mutex, since the thread would recheck the lock each time it started running again. I don't know if an OS would do this.

Comment: So in other words, OS switches between my threads whenever it "thinks" it is the best time to do so ?

Comment: @LaimonasSutkus - in the case of a Windows native mutex, it appears that the mutex locks are performed in the order requested, so a single mutex could be used to do a round robin share of a resource. I posted an example that shows this.